# '>=' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column `current_reveal` within a dataframe by comparing two column values `presses` and `num` grouped by `id`. If `presses` is greater than or equal to `num`, I would like to say 'True' in `reveal`.

Data looks like:

```py
data = {'id':  ['1','1','1','2','2'],
        'presses': ['1','3','2','10','7'],
        'num': ['6','2','5','7','10']}
```

And I want/the expected result would be:

```py
data = {'id':  ['1','1','1','2','2'],
        'presses': ['1','3','2','10','7'],
        'num': ['6','2','5','7','10'],
        'reveal': ['False','True','False','True','False']}
```

Currently, I have this line:

```
data['current_reveal']=(data.groupby('id')['presses'] >=
                         data.groupby('id')['num'])
```

but it is giving me the above type error.

Comment: Could you share with us some example data?

Comment: Sure, I added some sample data

Comment: What is the expected result and why did you think you needed group by for this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually `groupby` is used when you have multiple rows with the same `id`, so that you can calculate any statistics, like mean, sum, std, etc.. In your case you can just remove the `groupby` and it will work.

```
data['current_reveal'] = data['presses'] >= data['num']

# Output
  id  presses  num  current_reveal
0  1        1    6           False
1  2        3    2            True
2  3        2    5           False
3  4       10    7            True
```

Comment: I changed the data so that there are multiple of the same ID's. How would I approach it now?

Comment: I don't understand how did you calculate the `reveal` column. The second row has `num == 2` and `presses == 3`, but `reveals` is set to `False`, when it should be `True`, right? And the opposite occurs in the third row, where `num == 5` and `presses == 2`, but `reveals` is set to `True`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm formatting this on my phone, and I seem to have mistyped. Everything should be in order now. Thanks for checking over that.

Comment: No problem. I was just trying to make it out. Anyways, the solution to the problem remains the same. In essence, you're comparing `presses` directly with `num`, regarless of the `id`. You don't need `groupby` to do this. Unless you wanna do something else with the data after creating the `reveals` column